# None form fields unexpected in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have this django's file forms.py in my project.

```
from django import forms

class DateInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type='date'
    
class userRequest(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    lat_Origin = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lat_Origin"}),required=False,initial=181)
    lon_Origin = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lon_Origin"}),required=False,initial=181)
    lat_Dest = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lat_Dest"}),required=False,initial=181)
    lon_Dest = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={"id":"lon_Dest"}),required=False,initial=181)

    origin_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"data_aux data","id":"origin_address"}))
    destination_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"data_aux data","id":"destination_address"}))
```

I don't know why lat_Origin,lon_Origin,lat_Dest and lon_Dest are None in the post method
because they have an initial value of 181.

Here you can see the view:

```
def home(request):

    blablaTrips={}
    skyscannerTrips={}
    trips_busTrain={}


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userRequest(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print((form.cleaned_data))
        else:

            form = userRequest()
```

Here you can see the result of print(form.cleaned_data).

```
{'lat_Origin': None, 'lon_Origin': None, 'lat_Dest': None, 'lon_Dest': 
None, 'origin_address': 'Calle Francisco de Enzinas, 2, 09003 Burgos, España', 'destination_address': 'Avenida Diagonal, Barcelona, España', 'date': datetime.date(2021, 6, 11), 'maxPrice': None, 'OrderType': 'NONE', 'OrderBy': 'PRICE'}
```

[image]

I also edit django's form in a javascript file, but I obtain an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.

```
function get_address_withLocation(lat, lng, map, is_origin) {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    const latlng = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
    };
    geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
            if (results[0]) {
                map.setZoom(7);
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                });
                contentString =
                    '<div id="content-map">' +
                    '<p>' + results[0].formatted_address + '</p>' +
                    "</div>";
                infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);


                if (is_origin) {
                    document.getElementById('origin_address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    console.log(lat);
                    console.log(lng);
                    document.getElementById("lat_Origin").value = lat;
                    document.getElementById("lon_Origin").value = lng;
                    // document.getElementById("lat_Origin").value = 40;
                    // document.getElementById("lon_Origin").value = 2;

                    remove_mapMarkers('origin_address', marker)


                } else {
                    console.log(lat);
                    console.log(lng);
                    document.getElementById('destination_address').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                    document.getElementById("lat_Dest").value = lat;
                    document.getElementById("lon_Dest").value = lng;
                    remove_mapMarkers('destination_address', marker);


                }



            } else {
                window.alert("No results found");
            }

        } else {
            window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: This is only when you *render* a HTML form in the template. These thus only work for *unbound* forms (so without the `request.POST` data).

Comment: I think that no because I am trying to set a different value in a javascript file and I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: yes, if you work with an AJAX call, and you tamper with the data, then of course the bounded form will not contain the initial values, but `null`. The point is that it *renders* the form with the initial data, and in case the form is (properly) submitted, the initial values will then still be the values, and thus Django can work with that if it constructs a form with `request.POST`.

Answer (score 1):

As specified by the [documentation on **`initial=…`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial):

> (…) This is why initial values are only displayed for unbound forms. For bound forms, the HTML output will use the bound data.

So only for unbounded the forms (without `request.POST` passed as data), it will make use of the `initial`.

You thus can make a GET request with initial data, and if the user does not alter these, and makes a POST request, then these initial data will be part of the POST request.

```
def home(request):

    blablaTrips={}
    skyscannerTrips={}
    trips_busTrain={}
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userRequest(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print((form.cleaned_data))
    else:
        #            ↓ this form will work with the initial data
        form = UserRequest()
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: But in form = UserRequest(), I can not print form.cleaned_data. It gives me an error.

Comment: And in post method I continue obtaining a None value

Comment: @andriuu99: that is for the **GET** request, so to *render* the form on a template. After that the user will *submit* the form, and this is than done through a POST request. HTML will then properly encode the values of all the form fields, and thus take the `initial` value for fields if these did not change.

Comment: @andriuu99: you thus should *not* inspect the cleaned data of the `UserRequest`. This is the form constructed to *render* at the HTML page. The `UserRequest(request.POST)` will then analyze the POST request triggered by the HTML form.

Comment: But in the POST method I continue having problems with yout solution. I don't know why. I am working with javascript file and              document.getElementById("lat_Dest").value = lat; gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: If I print form.cleeaned_data in post method I obtain none values

Comment: I obtain none values only in Hidden Inputs, no in the rest of inputs.

Comment: can you share the JavaScript part where you submit the form. Please edit the question.

Comment: @andriuu99: but this is not the logic to *submit* the HTML form, this is more to "populate" form items.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I only want to save float location data in a django`s form to use it later.